# How to parse JSON with Aeson without declaring individual types

Tags: haskell, aeson

(Haskell newbie alert)

Here's a snippet of the code that I'm struggling with. Basically, I'm taking a JSON coming in from a websocket and I want to parse it using Aeson without defining individual data types for each response.

```
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Network.WebSockets  as WS

aria2WebsocketReceiver :: WS.Connection -> IO ()
aria2WebsocketReceiver conn = do
  msg <- WS.receiveData conn
  let res = decode msg
  let v = flip parseMaybe res $ \o -> do
                                      r <- o .: "result"
                                      version <- r .: "version"
                                      enabledFeatures <- r .: "enabledFeatures"
                                      id_ <- r .: "id"
                                      return $ "version=" ++ version
  putStrLn (show v)
  aria2WebsocketReceiver conn
```

Here are the compilation errors that I'm running into:

```
Nightwatch/Telegram.hs:244:13:
    No instance for (FromJSON a0) arising from a use of ‘decode’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      res :: Maybe a0 (bound at Nightwatch/Telegram.hs:244:7)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance FromJSON Chat -- Defined at Nightwatch/Telegram.hs:90:10
      instance FromJSON Message
        -- Defined at Nightwatch/Telegram.hs:106:10
      instance FromJSON TelegramResponse
        -- Defined at Nightwatch/Telegram.hs:122:10
      ...plus two others
    In the expression: decode msg
    In an equation for ‘res’: res = decode msg
    In the expression:
      do { msg <- WS.receiveData conn;
           let res = decode msg;
           let v = flip parseMaybe res $ ...;
           putStrLn (show v);
           .... }

Nightwatch/Telegram.hs:246:44:
    Couldn't match type ‘Maybe a0’
                   with ‘unordered-containers-0.2.5.1:Data.HashMap.Base.HashMap
                           Text Value’
    Expected type: Object
      Actual type: Maybe a0
    Relevant bindings include
      o :: Maybe a0 (bound at Nightwatch/Telegram.hs:245:34)
      res :: Maybe a0 (bound at Nightwatch/Telegram.hs:244:7)
    In the first argument of ‘(.:)’, namely ‘o’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: r <- o .: "result"
```

I'm basically trying to replicate the "Working with the AST" example given at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.10.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Cale at #haskell here's the working code:

```
aria2WebsocketReceiver :: WS.Connection -> IO ()
aria2WebsocketReceiver conn = do
  msg <- WS.receiveData conn
  let v = do res <- decode msg
             flip parseMaybe res $ \o -> do
                                         r <- o .: "result"
                                         version <- r .: "version"
                                         return $ "version=" ++ (version :: String)
  putStrLn (show v)
  aria2WebsocketReceiver conn
```

There were three problems in the earlier code:

1. The type of `decode msg` is a `Maybe` which needs to be inside a separate `do` block.
2. Because of `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` the compiler wasn't being able to infer the type for `version`, hence the `(version :: String)` hint.
3. Similarly, `enabledFeatures` and `id_` were being assigned but not being used anywhere, which was causing more problem in type-inference.

Comment: In regards to 3, this is a typical problem with Haskell (GHC) and especially with libraries with provide DSLs - they rely on *type inference* to work, and type inference only works if you actually use the type of a value somewhere! This is obviously fine in practice but when testing and experimenting you will often run into this situation. Generally speaking an "amiguous type" error corresponds to something like this (unused polymorphic value) - if you see this error look for this sort of thing.